# jQuery - Setting limits to number of appends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner, working on a personal project, where I am trying to make a tally system for a darts game called 'Cricket'.

Please visit my code below:

https://codepen.io/benszucs/pen/ZXdGxe

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').click(function(){
    var mark = $("<h1 class='mark'>I</h1>");
    if ($(".mark").length >= 3) return;
    $(this).closest('.count').append(mark);
  });
});
```

For each number there are a maximum 3 points(lines) a player can score. I managed to set a limit to the amount of lines I can append, however this applies to the whole application.

What I want is to be able to mark a maximum of three lines to each number (15 -> Bull), for each player.

Is there an easy fix I am missing, or am I approaching the problem in the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the elements with the `mark` class. So when you reach 3 elements, no matter which score, you are unable to add another mark.

A fix to this can be count the `mark` element from the element you click, something like:

```
if ($(this).parent().children().length >= 4) return;
```

In this code you count the number of children (`h1` elements) from the score element's parent you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the turn functionality to your app so that you can distinguish between whose turn it is currently.

But there is also a solution without that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("h1").click(function(){
  var mark = $("<h1 class='mark'>I</h1>");
  var current = ($(this).parents(".player.one").length > 0)?".one":".two";
  if ($(current +" .mark").length >= 3) return;
  $(this).closest('.count').append(mark); 
 });
});
```

In the code aboue I have added functionality for detection of **where** the user has clicked. If user clicks on **player one's** `<div class="player one">` then it checks how many points *player one* has scored and denies it the ability to score again if  player one has scored **three times** already.
Same goes for player two.

As you have just started the project I recommend you to disable the other player `div` until first player finishes his turn. Easiest way I recommend is using `pointer-events:none` CSS. This can be implemented in the above click listner.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.count').click(function(){
    if ($(this).children().length < 4)
      $(this).append("<h1 class='mark'>I</h1>");
  });
});
```

- first, `$('h1').click()`: this feels wrong/too generic to me. How easy is it to introduce another headline somewhere in the page and forget that there are click listeners attached to it.

  Adding the listener ti a class is way more specific, as you can name the class in a way that you don't use it anywhere else. And the only difference is, that you can now click the whole line, not just the number.
- `var mark = $("<h1 class='mark'>I</h1>");`: no need to wrap that into a jquery element yourself, especialln not if you don't know wether it will be added or not. You can sinply pass the template to `.append()`
- `if(...) return; //else-code`: I know this early out approach, and it is very useful to avoid nesting a lot of code into an else-block, but here we're talking about a single line. `if..then` feels more fluent *(as in reading a sentence)* than `if..abort ... otherwise`.

This ain't critique about your apprach. As your code works, and it's only a few lines. It's rather a reflection how I'd set this up, and why.